# Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200 with DigitalOcean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, digital-ocean

I am using DigitalOcean for my Ruby on Rails app with Elasticsearch. So I am getting

```
Faraday::ConnectionFailed in PetsController#create
Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200
```

I am wondering if it is because I am not using localhost on DigitalOcean. I am guessing if I have to change it in my app to start listening to the ip address I am using for DigitalOcean, but am not sure where I should look at.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can you check the following on digitalocean:

```
sudo vi /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

Look for:

```
network.bind_host: localhost
```

source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-on-an-ubuntu-vps

also, are you sure elasticsearch is running? The following command should give you a hash as result:

```
curl localhost:9200
```

If not: try to start it and try again:

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

Also, you'll probably want to boot elasticsearch automatically like described here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-service.html

Comment: I used to have that first, but I removed it. It didn't work with/without.

Comment: Updated the answer, please review

Comment: I did all of those before, but none worked. But what I just found out is that I start elasticsearch and check that it is running, and start rails server, things break, and when I quit rails server, I see that elasticsearch is also not running.

Comment: 'sudo service elasticsearch start' and then 'curl localhost:9200', what kind of response or errors do you get ?

Comment: I realized by running two terminal windows that elasticsearch was getting shut off when I was running the app. I upped the memory and it started working fine.